# Выдает ошибку "Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load."

Tags: java, javafx

Учусь делать dekstop-приложения с помощью JavaFX.

Столкнулась с проблемой, когда добавила onAction для button11, программа перестала запускаться и начала выдавать ошибку следующего рода:

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.
/C:/Users/Desktop/Diplom_game/out/production/Diplom_game/scene.fxml:16

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$RootElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1338)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at Main.start(Main.java:11)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application Main
```

Пыталась решить проблему прописыванием пути в getResource() - не помогло.
С чем еще может быть связано это?
В fxml контроллер тоже прописан.

TestApplication:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApplication extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("XO-game");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 165, 250));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML Label going;
    @FXML private Button button11;   


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void actionButton11(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        button11.setName("WOW");
        going.setText("WOWOWOW");
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема скорее всего в файле fxml: `Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.
/C:/Users/Desktop/Diplom_game/out/production/Diplom_game/scene.fxml:16`. Нужно смотреть что там в 16 строке.

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы. Разобралась в чем была ошибка.
Для таких же любящих наступать на непонятные грабли.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729277/javafx-fxml-load-file-issues-with-setting-root

Решилось заменой fx:root на VBox

Comment: Я думаю, это можно оформить ответом, только с примером как было и как исправили.

Comment: Отличная идея, так и сделаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решила проблему следующим образом:
Заменила в fxml-файле fx:root на VBox

Было:

```
<fx:root prefHeight="265.0" type="VBox" prefWidth="166.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
    ...
</fx:root>
```

Стало:

```
<VBox prefHeight="265.0" prefWidth="166.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
    ...
</VBox>
```

Проблема появилась в связи с тем, что в SceneBuilder поставила галочку в следующем окне:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]